# VIM - How to search and replace multiple strings using leader?

Tags: vim, search, vi

I'd like to make a leader shortcut for doing multiple global search and replaces in the current buffer.

For example, pressing leader then "fq", I'd like it to search and replace 3 times globally, replacing:

- "a" with "b"
- "c" with "d"
- "e" with "f"

I've read the help on it and think I'm close, but this doesn't work (seems to only do the first search):

```
map <leader>fq :%s/a/b/ge | %s/c/d/ge | %s/e/f/ge<CR>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command separator `|` has a higher precedence than the `:map` arguments, so you're effectively executing this:

```
:map <leader>fq :%s/a/b/ge
:%s/c/d/ge | %s/e/f/ge<CR>
```

You need to *escape* the `|` character, or better use the `<Bar>` special key notation when defining the mapping:

```
:map <leader>fq :%s/a/b/ge <Bar> %s/c/d/ge <Bar> %s/e/f/ge<CR>
```

PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: hey! thanks Ingo.... that totally fixed it up... much appreciated!